# A Library Class : Point

Tags: java, design-patterns, library, library-design

I am trying to create a *library* of my own which contains (among others), a `class` called **Point**. As the name suggests, it is intended to encapsulate a *point* represented in 2D space. This is what I've come up with:

```
package geom;

import static java.lang.Math.atan2;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static java.lang.Math.toDegrees;
import static java.lang.Math.toRadians;

/**
 * A class that provides factory methods for creation of {@code Points}, utility
 * functions based on operations regarding points.
 * <p>
 * The constructor has been made {@code private} because of the following
 * reason: A {@code Point} can be initialized in <i>two</i> different ways:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Using the <b>Cartesian System</b> of using two variables to represent the
 * coordinates of the {@code Point}.</li>
 * <li>Using the <b>Polar System</b> of using the distance from the original and
 * the angle between the line joining the point and the origin and the X-axis to
 * represent the location of the {@code Point}.</li>
 * </ul>
 * Since there are <i>two</i> parameters in both cases, and each is of the type
 * {@code double}, an ambiguity arises.
 * <p>
 * A solution to the above problem is to use <em>Factory Methods</em>.<br>
 * Factory methods are {@code public static} methods which can accessed through
 * class reference, like:
 * <p>
 * <code>Point point = Point.getCartesian(10, 20);</code><p>
 * The advantages of using Factory Methods are many; a few of them are:
 * <ol><li>Through the use of Factory Methods with descriptive names, the
 * ambiguity is removed.</li>
 * <li>These methods return a {@code new Point} if it has not been created
 * before.<br>
 * If a pre-existing point exists, the {@code Point} is returned from the
 * {@code PointTracker}.</li>
 * </ol>
 *
 *
 * @author ambigram_maker
 * @version 1.0
 * @version 2014-04-02
 */
public class Point {

    /*
     * This variable represents the state of the output.
     * It is static because any change to this variable is reflected in all the 
     * instances.
     */
    private static State state;
    /**
     * The Point object representing the reference point at the intersection of
     * the coordinate axes. Essentially, it is a point whose coordinates are
     * <pre>(0,0)</pre>.
     */
    public static final Point ORIGIN = getCartesianPoint(0, 0);

    /**
     * This factory method returns a {@code Point} object with the (Cartesian)
     * coordinates passed as parameters.
     *
     * @param x The X-coordinate of the {@code Point} object.
     * @param y The Y-coordinate of the {@code Point} object.
     * @return The required {@code Point} object.
     */
    public static Point getCartesianPoint(double x, double y) {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.x = x;
        p.y = y;
        p.radius = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        p.angleR = atan2(x, y);
        p.angleD = toDegrees(p.getAngleRadians());
        return p;
    }

    /**
     * This factory method returns a {@code Point} object with the (Polar)
     * coordinates passed as the parameters.
     *
     * @param radius The distance of the required {@code Point} from the origin
     * (0,0)
     * @param degrees The angle between the line joining the required
     * {@code Point} and the origin and the X-axis (in degrees i.e. from 0 to
     * 360).
     * @return The required {@code Point} object.
     */
    public static Point getPolarDegreesPoint(double radius, double degrees) {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.radius = radius;
        p.angleD = degrees;
        p.angleR = toRadians(degrees);
        initPolar(p);
        return p;
    }

    /**
     * This factory method returns a {@code Point} object with the (Polar)
     * coordinates passed as the parameters.
     *
     * @param radius The distance of the required {@code Point} from the origin
     * (0,0)
     * @param radians The angle between the line joining the required
     * {@code Point} and the origin and the X-axis (in radians i.e. from 0 to
     * 360).
     * @return The required {@code Point} object.
     */
    public static Point getPolarRadiansPoint(double radius, double radians) {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.radius = radius;
        p.angleR = radians;
        p.angleD = toDegrees(radians);
        initPolar(p);
        return p;
    }

    /*
     * This method is common to both the 'getPolar_______Point()' methods.
     */
    private static void initPolar(Point point) {
        double angle = point.getAngleRadians();
        point.x = point.getRadius() * cos(angle);
        point.y = point.getRadius() * sin(angle);
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to change the form of representation of <em>ALL</em>
     * {@code Point} objects.
     *
     * @see State
     * @param state The {@code State} constant to set.
     */
    public static void setState(State state) {
        Point.state = state;
    }

    /*
     * The coordinates of this Point in the Cartesian system.
     */
    private double x;       // The perpendicular distance from the Y-axis.
    private double y;       // The perpendicular distance from the X-axis.

    /*
     * The coordinates of this Point in the Polar System.
     */
    private double radius;  // The distance from the Origin (0,0).
    private double angleR;  // The angle in Radians.
    private double angleD;  // The angle in Degrees.

    private Quadrant location;
    /*
     * Instances of Point are not meant to be created through the default
     * contructor. Use the Factory Methods instead.
     */

    private Point() {
        // Provision to add itself to the PointTracker.
    }

    /**
     * Returns the <i>distance</i> between {@code this Point} and the one passed
     * in the parameter.
     *
     * @param other The <i>other</i> {@code Point} which acts as the reference
     * for calculating the distance.
     * @return The distance {@code this Point} and the <i>other</i> one.
     */
    public double distanceFrom(Point other) {
        return other.equals(Point.ORIGIN) ? radius
                : sqrt(pow(this.getX() - other.getX(), 2)
                        + pow(this.getY() - other.getY(), 2));
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the X-axis.
     *
     * @return Returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the X-axis.
     */
    public Point reflectionXAxis() {
        return getCartesianPoint(getX(), -getY());
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the Y-axis.
     *
     * @return Returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the Y-axis.
     */
    public Point reflectionYAxis() {
        return getCartesianPoint(-getX(), getY());
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the Origin.
     *
     * @return Returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the Origin.
     */
    public Point reflectionOrigin() {
        return getCartesianPoint(-getX(), -getY());
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the {@code Point} passed as a parameter.
     *
     * @param other The reference for calculating the reflection of
     * {@code this Point}
     * @return Returns the {@code Point} which is a reflection of
     * {@code this Point} in the X-axis.
     */
    public Point reflectionFrom(Point other) {
        if (other.equals(Point.ORIGIN)) {
            return reflectionOrigin();
        }
        return getCartesianPoint(
                2 * other.getX() - this.getX(),
                2 * other.getY() - this.getY());

    }

    /**
     * Returns the X-coordinate of {@code this Point}.
     * <p>
     * The magnitude of the X-coordinate is the perpendicular distance between
     * {@code this Point} and the Y-axis. If {@code this Point} is above the
     * X-axis, the X-coordinate is positive. If {@code this Point} is below the
     * X-axis, the X-coordinate is negative.
     *
     * @return the X coordinate of {@code this Point}.
     */
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Y-coordinate of {@code this Point}.
     * <p>
     * The magnitude of the Y-coordinate is the perpendicular distance between
     * {@code this Point} and the X-axis. If {@code this Point} is above the
     * Y-axis, the Y-coordinate is positive. If {@code this Point} is below the
     * Y-axis, the Y-coordinate is negative.
     *
     * @return the Y coordinate of {@code this Point}.
     */
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the distance between the origin (0,0) and {@code this Point}.
     * Considering the origin to be at the center and {@code this Point} at the
     * circumference, this distance is the <i>radius</i>.
     *
     * @return The Distance between the origin and {@code this Point}.
     */
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the angle between the line joining {@code this Point} and the
     * origin, and the X-axis in Radians.
     *
     * @return The angle between the line joining {@code this Point} and the
     * origin, and the X-axis in Radians.
     */
    public double getAngleRadians() {
        return angleR;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the angle between the line joining {@code this Point} and the
     * origin, and the X-axis in Degrees.
     *
     * @return The angle between the line joining {@code this Point} and the
     * origin, and the X-axis in Degrees.
     */
    public double getAngleDegrees() {
        return angleD;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the <i>location</i> of {@code this Point} in a broader
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Quadrant getLocation() {
        if (location == null) {
            if (this.equals(Point.ORIGIN)) {
                location = Quadrant.ON_ORIGIN;
            } else if (x == 0) {
                location = Quadrant.ON_Y_AXIS;
            } else if (y == 0) {
                location = Quadrant.ON_X_AXIS;
            } else if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
                location = Quadrant.FIRST_QUADRANT;
            } else if (x < 0 && y > 0) {
                location = Quadrant.SECOND_QUADRANT;
            } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
                location = Quadrant.THIRD_QUADRANT;
            } else if (x > 0 && y < 0) {
                location = Quadrant.FOURTH_QUADRANT;
            }
        }
        return location;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to check if two instances of {@code Point} are equal.
     * This method checks the {@code Point}s using their hashcodes.
     *
     * @see Point#hashCode()
     * @param o The {@code Object} to compare this instance with.
     * @return {@code true} if the {@code  Object} passed as parameter is an
     * instance of type {@code Point} and the two {@code Point}s are
     * <i>equal</i>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Point) {
            Point p = (Point) o;
            return this.hashCode() == p.hashCode();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getX())
                ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getX()) >>> 32));
        hash += (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getY())
                ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.getY()) >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Thread t = new Thread();
        String summary = "\tCartesian:\t( x\t: " + x + ", y\t: " + y + " )";
        if (state == null) {
            setState(State.SHORT_SUMMARY);
        }
        if (!state.equals(State.NO_SUMMARY)) {
            summary += "\n\tPolar:\n\t\tDegrees\t( radius\t: " + radius + ", angle\t: "
                    + angleD + " )\n";
            summary += "\t\tRadians\t( radius\t: " + radius + ", angle\t: "
                    + angleR + " )\n";
        }
        if (state.equals(State.LONG_SUMMARY)) {
            summary += "\tQuadrant\t: " + getLocation();
            // summary += "\n\t" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
        }
        return summary;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("PublicInnerClass")
    public static enum State {

        /**
         * If the {@code state} of a {@code Point} is set to this value, then
         * the {@code toString()} will display:
         * <ol>
         * <li>Cartesian Representation : (x,y)</li>
         * <li>Polar Representation (r,θ) in :
         * <ul><li>Degrees</li><li>Radians</li></ul></li>
         * <li>The quadrant in which the {@code Point} is located.</li>
         * </ol>
         */
        LONG_SUMMARY,
        /**
         * If the {@code state} of a {@code Point} is set to this value, then
         * the {@code toString()} will display:
         * <ol>
         * <li>Cartesian Representation : (x,y)</li>
         * <li>Polar Representation (r,θ) in :
         * <ul><li>Degrees</li><li>Radians</li></ul></li>
         * </ol>
         *
         */
        SHORT_SUMMARY,
        /**
         * If the {@code state} of a {@code Point} is set to this value, then
         * the {@code toString()} will display the Cartesian Representation :
         * (x,y) of this {@code Point}.
         */
        NO_SUMMARY;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PublicInnerClass")
    public static enum Quadrant {

        FIRST_QUADRANT,
        SECOND_QUADRANT,
        THIRD_QUADRANT,
        FOURTH_QUADRANT,
        ON_X_AXIS,
        ON_Y_AXIS,
        ON_ORIGIN;
    }
}
```

---

I used NetBeans 8.0 to create the above class, so the arrangement, the *warning suppression* has been suggested by this software. I need people to criticize and discuss upon:

1. The effectiveness of the code.
2. The organization of the code.
3. Possible ways to *improve* the performance, readability, simplicity, etc.
4. **Is the *hashing* good enough?**
5. Any errors in the documentation (technical, accidental) of the code.
6. Any other aspect focused upon improvement of my programming skills.

through downvotes (and upvotes?<sup>1</sup>), comments and answers (of course!). Please note that **this is a library class that anyone can use or modify**, but inform me first.

---

### EDIT:

After *[encountering]* so many varied answers, I have decided to change these aspects:

1. As suggested by [RoToRa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/2035/rotora) in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46179/37479) answer, I'll get rid of the `State` idea completely, because it is actually temporary.
2. From the same answer, I'll change the name of the factory methods to start with `create...`.
3. Fix the *bug* pertaining to the angle (from the same answer).
4. Modify the `hashcode()` and `equals()` method. (I have done it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860639/how-do-i-correct-my-hash-function)).
5. As suggested by [coredump](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37033/coredump) in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46186/37479) answer, I'll change `initPolar()` (or maybe even get rid of it).
6. As suggested by [Eike Schulte](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/34451/eike-schulte) in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46209/37479) answer, I'll fix the `atan2(y,x)` bug.
7. As suggested by [ChrisW](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/34757/chrisw) over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46169/37479), I'll use `pow(..)` throughout.
8. Use a *5-parameter constructor* (for use by the factory methods).

(These changes haven't been applied to the code above.)

- In addition to these, I'm thinking of adding a `scale` variable (`double`) that is used to decide the degree of accuracy (and overcome the [*floating-point issues*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189081/how-to-overcome-inaccuracy-in-java)). Is it really practical?
- **Justification for `PointTracker`:**
  I'll add a post later on about the class `PointTracker` after some time. This class is (as the name suggests) supposed to track (all?) the `Points` created during runtime. It'll add support for *yet another library class*: `Line`. (Hence, you can expect quite a few posts related to this topic.)
- **Last, but not the least** I invite more answers pertaining to topics other than those resolved above, so that this `Point` is the *ideal* class. I also invite demonstrations of *just-in-time* implementations of the **inter-conversion of the angles** or other related operations.

*Please guys, remember that this is for **you**; so give suggestions to make it more **personal***.

---

<sup>1 : Help CodeReview [graduate](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/what-are-the-advantages-of-graduation)!</sup>

Comment: The hashing could be more effective but it's actually fine. The `equals` depending on `hashCode` is very bad. We would not expect `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)` to be considered equal and right now they are.

Comment: Why bother special-casing the origin in `reflectionFrom`?

Comment: Why is it mutable?

Comment: @user2357112 As I've commented below ChrisW's answer: _"Using this.equals(ORIGIN) helps save some time coz, the dist. b/w `this Point` and `Point.ORIGIN` is already stored --> `radius`"_. But then again, I don't know if it's practical.

Comment: @Alex I didn't want it to be, but I had to make it mutable to implement the _factory methods_. Now, I can make x, y, radius, etc. `final` thanks to all the generous people of CodeReview. :-)

Comment: @ambigram_maker: It adds additional code complexity and some overhead for the not-origin case, which probably isn't worth it. Furthermore, it's premature optimization. You don't know whether the case where the other point is the origin is common enough, and the savings in that case great enough, that it even improves the average runtime of the method.

Comment: @user2357112 So... I guess -"down with the `if-else`"_ then?

Answer (score 16):

Use use of a "state" to distinguish between different output formats is very wrong. If you need different formats, use multiple output methods (have `toString` just for debug output), or even better, write a separate class for converting `Point`s to a string representation.

I think you have overdone it with the JavaDoc. IMHO it's neither the place for theoretical excursus on how coordinate systems work, nor the place to discuss implementation decisions ("Since there are *two* parameters in both cases, and each is of the type {@code double}, an ambiguity arises.").

The names of the factory methods shouldn't begin with `get...` since they are not getters. Use  `create...` instead.

You should modulo the degrees to 360 (and the radians to 2π) otherwise you get:

```
Point p1 = Point.getPolarDegreesPoint(10,45);
Point p2 = Point.getPolarDegreesPoint(10,405);
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // prints false, but should be true.
```

The use of the hash code inside the equals not good. One of the functions of `equals` is to distinguish between two objects with the same hash code - which will happen, considering you are "squeezing" two 64 bit double values into a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Thanks for the loophole about the angle... And could (please?) demonstrate a _better_ way to **hash** the `Points`?

Comment: The hash is ok. Just don't use it in the `equals()` method.

Comment: I have edited the question, so please take a look.

Answer (score 13):

### 1. Why `static` ?

I have a minor issue with the following:

> private static void initPolar(Point point) {

Why do you define a static function when the argument is an instance of a `Point` and thus could be a method?

```
private void initPolar() {
    double angle = getAngleRadians();
    x = getRadius() * cos(angle);
    y = getRadius() * sin(angle);
}
```

### 2. Do you need caching ?

> If a pre-existing point exists, the {@code Point} is returned from the {@code PointTracker}

This looks like premature optimization to me. What is the intended benefits of storing and looking up points in a cache (which takes time and memory) instead of creating multiple instances of points. How likely it is that points will be created at the exact same location?

How are you going to implement the tracker? using a hash map? will you create a temporary point just to check whether it already belongs to the set and discard it in order to return the stored instance?

Besides, if you really need caching, this is not the responsability of the `Point`  class to do it. The class exposes a `hash` function so that other classes can use it.

### 3. Class hierarchy

It has already been suggested, but you can define two kind of points, "polar" and "cartesian" ones, both having well-defined public constructors:

```
 public CartesionPoint (double x, y) ...
 public CartesionPoint (PolarPoint pp) ...

 public PolarPoint (double radius, radians) ...
 public PolarPoint (CartesionPoint cp) ...
```

If you really want to build PolarPoint with either radians/degrees, maybe your constructor can take an optional unit parameter (e.g. RADIANS or DEGREES, defined in an enum type).

I hope I don't sound too harsh. Good luck :-)

Comment: As for #2, you are absolutely right: I will create a `PointTracker` class for the same.

Comment: @ambigram_maker That's good, but I honestly don't understand why you need a `PointTracker`; is it really necessary?

Comment: I have edited the question, so please take a look.

Comment: @ambigram_maker Let's try another approach: in [the standard library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), I see no `FileTracker`, `DoubleTracker` nor `InputStreamTracker` (there *is* a `MediaTracker` class, though). If anyone wants to track points in their applications, they will do it. *But **you** can't do this in a generic way*: will you use spatial hashing? or simply lists? you can't know what is good for everyone; I'am afraid you are over-architecting *this part* of the library. I'd suggest writing applications to test its API: try a bottom-up approach instead of a top-down one.

Comment: Very nice answer!  Feel free to join us in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime!

Answer (score 10):

The `Math.atan2` function is defined rather strangely (not only in Java, but in every programming language I know) and the correct use is `atan2(y, x)`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `atan2` or anything in math, but why would it be the correct use ? Should you call the Java version with `atan2(y, x)` or not ?

Comment: @Marc-Andre [Java's atan2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) wants `y, x`: but the OP wrote `x, y` which therefore seems to be a bug.

Comment: I have edited the question, so please take a look.

Answer (score 8):

This will be an incomplete review because I don't really know Java.

Instead of `State` maybe call it `SummaryType` or `FormatType`.

In `distanceFrom` I don't see why you have a special case for `other.equals(Point.ORIGIN)`; and given that you do, I don't see why you don't also have a special case for `this.equals(Point.ORIGIN)`.

Your implementation of `equals` might be buggy: if points are equal then their hash codes are equal; but different points might be able to have the same hash code.

You're carrying redundant/duplicate information in each instance: e.g. the angle in degrees and in radians. You could store only one and calculate the other just-in-time if it's asked for. Similarly you're pre-calculating and storing its cartesian and its polar representation: would it be better to store one and calculate the other just-in-time; or have two different classes (`CartesianPoint` and `PolarPoint`) for the two different representations?

Sometimes you use `pow(..., 2)` and sometimes you use `x * x`: is that deliberate?

Are there values (along an axis) for which `atan2` doesn't work well because its behaviour is asymptotic?

Calculated points risk being never-equal due to rounding errors. It's usual with floating-point to arithmetic to decide they're 'equal' if they're "close enough". That could interfere with hashing though (if it's required that equal values must have equal hashes). So you might want to define another function "nearlyEqual" which returns true if `distanceFrom` is less than some small epsilon.

Because of rounding errors you may find anomalies e.g. that a point initialized using polar coordinates doesn't return the right `getLocation()` value. If you had two classes then the `getLocation` method for the polar class could do its test using the angle instead of using the `x` and `y` values.

Do you want to use `double` for your `x` and `y` types? It might be better (e.g. so that you don't have trouble comparing `1` with `1.0000000000000001`) to use `int` instead, if that's appropriate for example if `x` and `y` are measures of integer pixel value.

I'd like to see a list of unit-tests, so that I know what values you have tested it for.

This comment is untrue (not implemented):

> If a pre-existing point exists, the {@code Point} is returned from the {@code PointTracker}.

It might be better if the data members were `final`. You could implement this even when you have multiple factory methods, by:

- Having a constructor which takes all values via parameters
- Calculate all those parameter values in the static factory methods, and then call the constructor.

Comment: My `package` is incomplete, just like your review. (-> JOKE: No Offence!) :-) I have yet to implement my `PointTracker` (see the body of my constructor (but that's another post).

Comment: I'm prefering _factory methods_ to the constructor because of the _ambiguity issue_: read (or try to :-) )the documentation just above the main class for justification.

Comment: I'm intentionally using `double` for `x` and `y`, instead of `int` (that's why I need some hint regarding **hashing** and **equality**).

Comment: Using `this.equals(ORIGIN)` helps save some time coz, the dist. b/w `this Point` and `Point.ORIGIN` is already stored --> `radius`.

Comment: @ambigram_maker I understand why you have factory methods (though it might be better to have different classes, one for Cartesian and one for Polar). If your members are final (which perhaps they could/should be) then I think you initialize them in one place e.g. in a constructor. Having a non-trivial constructor is not incompatible with having factory methods: you can have a constructor which takes all 5 parameters, and calculate those 5 parameter values in the factory method.

Comment: I have edited the question, so please take a look.

Answer (score 8):

One line review

I don't see any use of `Thread t = new Thread()`  in `toString` method.

Comment: I have edited the question, so please take a look.

Comment: @ambigram_maker The point is that you SHOULDN'T.

Comment: @ambigram_maker ehhh what are you saying? you have done it. See your code.

Comment: :-O. Man... I've gone crazy!

Answer (score 7):

If a class is supposed to serve as a data holder, two instances which report themselves as equal should have the same properties; further, values corresponding to constructor/factory parameters should match the values used in creating the object.  It would be possible to have a polar-coordinate type whose properties were the rho and theta values, or an xy coordinate type, whose properties were x and y, or perhaps even an abstract coordinate type with subtypes that hold degree-polar coordinates, radian-polar coordinates, and xy coordinates (each of which would store a different set of properties).  Defining how the latter should work, though, could be tricky.

Consider what happens, for example, if one constructs a point with polar coordinates (angle=45 degrees, radius=2.0) and then constructs another point whose xy coordinates match the first.  Any possible behavior by the class is apt to be "surprising", since the xy-constructed object will have a radius of 2.0000000000000004; this means that either:

- The xy-constructed object won't be equal to another object whose coordinates are reportedly the same, or
- The xy-constructed object, though supposedly equal to the polar-constructed one, will have a different radius, or
- The radius of the polar-constructed object won't match the specified value.

Of these, perhaps the first would be most justifiable if one says that degree-polar objects are unequal to any xy object except when the angle is a multiple of 90 degrees, and radian-polar objects are unequal to any other object except when the angle is zero.  Even though the closest `double` to the polar-degree object's x coordinate is 1.4142135623730951, the actual x coordinate is closer to 1.4142135623730950488016887242097, so it won't quite match any point whose xy coordinates are specified using a `double`.

Unless there's some particular reason for using polar coordinates, I'd suggest having the `Point` type explicitly encapsulate an `x` and `y`, both of type `double`.  Use `public final` fields for those and set them in a private constructor.  Even if you have other methods which can construct a point for a given radius and angle, or report the radius and angle associated with a point, make it clear that reported values are not inherent properties of the object, but simply calculations based upon its x and y.

Comment: I have edited the question, so please take a look.

Comment: Your edit doesn't address the biggest issue, which is whether a request to construct a point with (angle=45deg; radius=2.0) should yield a point with exactly that angle and radius, or whether it should yield the nearest point whose x and y coordinates are representable.  As for `PointTracker`, I would suggest that `Point` itself should handle caching (with the assistance of one or more other classes), but allow allow the factory methods' callers to indicate when caching is particularly likely to be helpful.  With regard to caching of computations, I would suggest...

Comment: ...that it might be useful to have your `Point` hold an `X` and `Y`, and a reference to a `PointInfo` object which could have additional information, including possibly a sequence number and the identity of another lower-sequenced `PointInfo` which is known to be equal.  Using such an approach would mean that if two points are compared and found to be equal, the result of any computation upon either (whether performed before or after the comparison) would be cached for both.  Further, if A has found equal to B and B to C, then computations on A would be cached for C.

Comment: There are some wrinkles one needs to be careful of in such a design to avoid having things go bonkers if points are accessed in different threads, but it could still be an interesting approach.

Comment: Well... as for the accuracy issue: _" I'm thinking of adding a `scale` variable"_ as I've said in the edit. This ought to take care of minor adjustments (like rounding) but has yet to be implemented.

Comment: @ambigram_maker: Adding a `scale` variable is apt to make equivalence even murkier than its absence.  Java collections expect that objects can be divided into equivalence classes [mathematical term], such that all of them objects in each equivalence class are equivalent to each other, and none of them are equivalent to anything outside the class.  Strings are divided into equivalence classes based on character sequence; two strings are equivalent if and only if they contain the same characters.  How should `Point`'s equivalence classes be defined?